How and when is voting fraud investigated?
As you all know, Up and Down voting questions on all Stack Exchange sites is a crucial part of network’s functionality, because it not only decides how correct or relevant questions and answers are, it also provides useful contributors with reputation (and of course downvoting being the opposite.)
But, and here’s the big ‘but’, voting fraud can ruin Q and A’s, and give unearned reputation as well.
Here: What is a vote fraud? is another question about what voting fraud actually is, so I won’t repeat that question, but what I want to know is who decides and moderates voting fraud, because according to one of the answers on another question, and correct me if I’m wrong, but even Moderators can’t easily see who votes!
So if mods can’t, who can moderate voting fraud then?

This is explained in our FAQ What is serial voting and how does it affect me?, section I've flagged my post for moderator attention to report voting fraud; how does the investigation process work?

Simply, as a moderator when we have indicators voting fraud has happened (and we have limited tools for it) or notice something strange going on, we kick it up to the community team. They can actually view who voted for whom, and have some tools that let them do broader analysis and act based on that.
There's a lot of black boxes in the process for obvious reasons, but in general, we tend to escalate situations that are too big for our tools to the community team, and they have much better access to information (and developers!) than we do.
